# Trying to add a Captcha to a form created in FreeForm

Tags: solspace

First time posting.  Did a cursory search on this subject but didn't find what I was looking for.  If the answer is already in another thread, feel free to redirect me there and I will read it very carefully!

The organisation I work for, a non-profit called Volunteer Bénévoles Yukon, uses ExpressionEngine for our website hosted at volunteeryukon.ca.  We have a contact form (created with Freeform Pro 4.2.2) at this URL http://volunteeryukon.ca/contact/.  It's been there for years without any sort of CAPTCHA and it wasn't an issue, but over the last 6 months or so, the amount of spam messages we've received through it have triggered us to look for ways to reduce such.

Initially, I thought to add a CAPTCHA to the form, and in ExpressionEngine, when I navigate to Forms -> Composer (for said form), which takes me into Freeform Pro 4.2.2, I was able to add a Captcha above the Send button on the form. I saved, came back in the same way, and confirmed the Captcha addition took.  But... when I browse back to the contact form as an anonymous browser, there is no Captcha showing up, and the form can still be filled out by anyone for anything (including, it would seem, spam bots).

I tried to click on Help (in the same menu bar as Forms) but it takes me to a "Whoops! (a.k.a. 404 Not Found)" (the URL is https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/add-ons/module_manager.html).

I'm not sure what steps I might be missing.  The form looks right (with the added CAPTCHA) in Composer / Freeform Pro 4.2.2, but the Captcha just isn't showing up on the actual form browsers view.  Help?"

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an indirect solution, but you might find it better all around to solve this a different way, by installing [snaptcha](https://putyourlightson.com/expressionengine-addons/snaptcha) - a truly excellent utility.  There is almost no installation (simply install and enable the add-on and it will do the rest) and no captcha box to worry about - 'it just works'.

The add-on has a small fee.

Have used it in the past on a Freeform Pro form and it works fine with the add-on - when we installed it spam was eliminated, simple as that.

HTH

Comment: Really, I confirm that Snaptcha is great. Working well with Freeform.

Comment: The later versions have a built in honeypot.

Comment: Thank you jcogs.eecms, Stéphane, and Jim Wyse! I'll look into snaptcha.